# Send data with $broadcast on button click and take that data with $scope.$on

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, events, angular-ui-router

I want in function  for button click to $broadcast data that i am getting from server, and then to call $state.go('new-route'). In controller for this new state i want to retrieve that data. But when i try to take data with $on it is undefined, event is not listening...Below you can find my code.

**MainController**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app').controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$state',
    function ($scope, $state) {

      $scope.takeData = null;

      //Here i am getting data from server
      $scope.takeData = dataFromServer;

      $scope.buttonClick = function () {
            $scope.$broadcast('send-data', $scope.takeData);
            $state.go('newstate');
        };

    }
]);
```

**View for MainController**

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="buttonClick ()"><i
                        class="fa fa-edit"></i> {{Click Button}}
                </button>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**New Controller**

'use strict';

```
angular.module('app').controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$state',
    function ($scope, $state) {

      $scope.$on('send-data', functiopn(e, data){
            $scope.getData = data;  
      });

     $scope.useData = function(){
       // Here i want to use retrieved data
       console.log($scope.getData);
      //this returns undefined
     }

    }
]);
```

Comment: You have a typo in function on $scope.$on. Also how the two controllers are related to each other? is the second controller in a child scope of the first controller?

Comment: It is not typo in my code, just here that is now problem. I tried with broadcast and emit also but in event listener function never goes.. It is messing something with route and broadcast....

Comment: Hum, you can of course always supply params when you go to another state. In your case you would not need to broadcast. 
See here: http://benfoster.io/blog/ui-router-optional-parameters => Non-Url route parameters.

Comment: hm... will see this how i can send params ... but i don't know if that will hepl me.. cause data i am taking from service in MainController and hot to put in ruting that data...

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.$broadcast` would only work if your "New Controller" is a child of "MainController", is that the case?

if not, you can either rearrange your controllers so that "MainController" is the parent controller of "New Controller"

**OR**

if you want to keep them as sibling controllers, you inject `$rootScope` into each controller, and then use `$rootScope.$broadcast` and `$rootScope.$on` to listen for the event.  I believe `$rootScope.$broadcast` works with sibling controllers.

Comment: Well i guess that is why when i was debugging it was never going in even listener function in NewController...So they are sibling controller, then i guess i should use $rootscope.$broadcast. But maybe again that will mess up again with routing ($state.go) or not...?

Comment: Well i tried with $rootScope.$broadcast and $rootScope.$on but again when debugging it is not going in function for event listener it is going in $scope.useData function and there data is undefined....

Comment: well when are you calling useData? try calling $scope.useData in your event listener function, so then when you console.log  $scope.getData, it will happen after the event listener is fired